# How to assign the object type for a list in java?

Tags: java, list, oop

Let's say that I have a class :

```
class Person{
  String name = "";
  int age = 0;
  Person(String name, String age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

I implemented my own List but I don't know how to specify the object type like traditional List : `List<Person>`.
If I let the default class to "Object" it works but I cannot access the variables and methods from my object. For example `print( list.get(0) )` is going to show the reference for my object but print( list.get(0).name ) it's not going to work. I want for my list to work on any class.

This is how I declare my implemented list :

```
List list = new List();
list.add( new Person("Andrei", 19) );
```

Here is my code : [link](https://pastebin.com/DWkU1PkS)

Comment: Use generics: `List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: I build my list from scratch

Comment: @LutzHorn Valentin is using a custom implementation of a list, not `java.util.List`

Comment: In that case, make your `List` class generic or cast the Object to a person after you get()

Comment: @Valentin Please tell us *why* you want to implement your own list?

Comment: I want to learn how data structures works.

Comment: Why don't you downcast to Person class? Check instance and downcast

Comment: I want the list to work for every class, but I don't want to cast every time I use the object variables and methods.

Comment: For the learning purposes I'd go with the current implementation for now. To make it work like `List<Person>` you will need to learn about **generics** as well.

Comment: Can you please share your List class declaration. I am not seeing it in the provided code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yQQnWnac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your LinkedList generic and also the embedded Node so you can define the data field in Node as an instance of your passed type:

```
class Node<T>{
    T data;// Object data
    Node next;

    Node(T d){
        this.data = d;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
public class LinkedList<T> {
    Node<T> first = null;
    Node<T> last = null;
    // TODO change all your methods to accept value of type T instead of Object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you linked to from your question, your `LinkedList` class is not generic. To make it generic you can define it as follows...

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
}
```

However, since your `LinkedList` class contains only `Node`s, you should rather just make your `Node` class generic. Something like...

```
class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node next;

    Node(T d){
        this.data = d;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a *Person* `Node` like so...

```
Node<Person> personNode = new Node<>(new Person("George", 20));
```

By the way, I suggest renaming your `LinkedList` class since there is already such a [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) in the standard java library of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your list class should use generics

```java
public class MyList<T> {
    public T getAtIndex(int i) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Then you can create one like this

```java
MyList<Person> = new MyList<Person>();
```

I would also suggest to extend List with

```java
public class MyList<T> extends List<T>
```

Which provides standard methods such as get

```java
@Override
public T get(int index) {
    return ...;
}
```